# Why did Patty call the cops when she found out Dewey was posing as Ned?

Tags: plot-explanation, school-of-rock

Perhaps a weird question but in "School of Rock" Starring Jack Black, why did Patty call the cops when she found out Dewey was posing as Ned? Wasn't that ridiculous since it didn't really seem like too much of a crime - as Dewey said to Patty "it's not like I murdered anybody"?

Comment: "Identity theft is not a joke Jim!"

Comment: You seriously think it's ridiculous to call the cops if you discover one of the "teachers" in your school committed fraud in order to get the job? A job that involves having unmonitored access to a class of fifth-graders?

Answer (score 1):

Pretending to be a teacher, to get close to kids, that is something that is highly illegal. Identity theft, especially when it comes to using someone else's identity for monetary gain, is very illegal. If she did not call the police, technically they could get in trouble, for not reporting identity theft when it happened. They could easily be considered accomplices, in lying to an organization that raises children.